# Adobe Acrobat app.alert() in Arabic Language

Tags: javascript, pdf

I am writing a code to submit PDF form through PHP to MySQL, but there is some javascript validation, which should display error message as below.

app.alert(strAlertMsg);

when the error message in Arabic Language its rubbish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution simply was typing Arabic text in ANSI and copy them into the app.alert text, they will be displayed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, you should be able to display the string properly if it is encoded in UTF-16.

If that fails, you could set up a hidden field with the error message, and show (and then hide) it with your validation code.

Comment: Thanks For Answering, I am trying to display all error messages and alerts in Arabic Language, and it appears like symbols.